# laravel 5 primary key column not named id

Tags: migration, laravel-5

Im trying to migrate our current application over to Laravel-5.
This app has quite a big structure with many tables, but way less than half of the tables has a `primary key` called `id`.
Is this a problem or can you manualy specify what you want your primary key to be called.
Its just that from the training videos I am doing, it seems like no.

Comment: Training videos are nice, but please also read the [official docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#basic-usage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just add `$table->primary('field')` to your database shema as mentioned here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#adding-indexes

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
protected $primaryKey = 'Your_Primary_key';
```

In the Models.

Answer (score 0):

```
$table->string('your_primary_key', 32)->primary();
```

'your_primary_key' is the name's primary key

32 is length

I try and it work